# Xamarin Android App not streaming online radio stream

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, internet-radio

So I'm trying to make a Android app for an online radio and no matter how much I use the guides on Xamarin, it's not streaming.

My code: http://pastebin.com/K20RX8Yk

The coding environment I am using is Xamarin.Android and I am coding in the Xamarin Studio. I've been using the Android emu running API 16.

I have already tried different path files but sadly that hasn't fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to use the MediaPlayer to stream audio on Android, as it is much easier to use then AudioTrack. Potentially AudioTrack could have better performance but you need to do quite some stuff yourself to get it working correctly.

Here is a blog post with example how to use MediaPlayer on Xamarin Android: http://blog.xamarin.com/background-audio-streaming-with-xamarin.android/

A quick example out of that is:

```
private const string Mp3 = @"http://167.88.113.131:8000/;stream.mp3";
private MediaPlayer player;

private void IntializePlayer()
       {
            player = new MediaPlayer();

            //Tell our player to sream music
            player.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.Music);
}

private async void Play()
        {
            if (player == null) {
              IntializePlayer();
            }

            try {
                await player.SetDataSourceAsync(ApplicationContext, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(Mp3));
                player.PrepareAsync();
                player.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                //unable to start playback log error
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to start playback: " + ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried adding this code into my project but i am getting these errors http://i.imgur.com/4bOorGN.png I have tried changing the classes from private to public but that didn't change anything.

Comment: You need to remove any references to system.io.stream and add a reference to android.media.steam

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/GIzGque.png Here are all my references. I didn't have any with system.io.stream so i added android.media.stream and then the following error, which can be seen in the imgur link, appeared.

Comment: Use Android.Media.MediaPlayer = player; for the media player.